# How to pass Wordpress the_title(); tag through Gravity Form shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, gravity

I am trying to dynamically populate an invisible field in a Gravity form with the WP post title. Right now I have:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="9" field_values="trip_of_interest=the_title();"]'); ?>
```

However, this ultimately gives me a value of "the_title();", but does not give me the actual title itself.

**Edit:** The field is now being passed correctly using:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="9" title="false" field_values="trip_of_interest=' . the_title('','',FALSE) . '"]'); ?>
```

However, if the post title contains an apostrophe, the value that is passed is everything before that apostrophe only, not the complete title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a PHP function inside a string like that. Need to use concatenation.

Also you need to set the optional third param to `FALSE` to return rather than echo the title.

```
echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="9" field_values="trip_of_interest=' . the_title('','',FALSE) . '"]'); ?>
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used WordPree, but doesn't the_title automatically echo out to the browser? As such, shouldn't the function be get_the_title() ?

Comment: @LiamWiltshire you are correct, `the_title()` echoes by default so this answer should use `get_the_title()` instead (which only returns but does not echo the title).

Comment: @LiamWiltshire Yep, you're right. I updated my answer, there is an optional third param that returns rather than echos the title.

Comment: Although he just edited to include the final parameter which prevents it from echoing, so answer as-is works.

Comment: @jszobody It is now passing the field properly. However, if the title has a single quote in it, it is only passing the characters before that quote. For example if the title were "John's Book" it is simply passing "John"

Comment: @johnnyd23 sounds like you need to escape the title then

Comment: @jszobody Not sure what you're saying

Comment: @johnnyd23 If you have a title like `some'thing` with a single quote in it, you can see that your output would be `trip_of_interest='some'thing'`. It's obvious why this is breaking things for you. You may need to escape it so that you have `trip_of_interest='some\'thing'` or you may need to encode so that you have `trip_of_interest='some&#39;thing'` or you may just want to use double quotes so that you have `trip_of_interest="some'thing"`.

Comment: @jszobody I understand the logic, I'm just confused as to how to implement since I'm using the_title() within the attribute of an attribute. I also thought characters like the apostrophe were already converted in the_title() with wptexturize. 

I tried using the double quotes but this did not work as it is already wrapped in doubles: `field_values="trip_of_interest="""`. I also tried using `the_title_attribute()` instead but have not gotten this to work.

Comment: @jszobody got this working by using: `do_shortcode('[gravityform id="9" title="false" field_values="trip_of_interest=' . urlencode(get_the_title()) . '"]');`. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I did add this as a comment to jszobody's comment, but thought I would add it here for clarity.

the the_title() function in WordPress echos the title out to the browser - which isn't really the functionality you are after here.

There is a seperate function, get_the_title() which will return the title to be used as part of another string, so the required code would be:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="9" field_values="trip_of_interest=' . get_the_title() . '"]'); ?>
```